# Tesseract c++ app runs locally and not crashes on server

Tags: c++, visual-c++, ocr, tesseract

i am new to c++ and have experience in c# only.

I tried to use tesseract in simple c++ project
when i build the c++ project in local machine it works properly.
when i deploy the application in server it is not working.
I installed the tesseract using vcpkg as per the instruction given tesseract github

My local machine is windows 10 and i tried in two servers, windows server 2012 and 2016.
I checked the version of vc++ installed on both servers and local and they are same vc++ 2017 and have both x86 and 64.
After the build i checked the release folder and there is no dll file for tesseract but it runs locally.
while installing the tesseract using vcpkg i saw some output in console stating that tesseract will be installed as static link.

The program does not step into main function where i have print as first line.Seems problem with tesseract c++ static link

Please help

**Update**

It seems there is no problem with static link.
i am able to run the application in windows 10 machines.
only not able to run in windows server 2012 and windows server 2016

**Update 1**

I tried to find out problem by removing and adding code based on #include statement. When i place the following line related to tesseract the application crashes

```
tesseract::TessBaseAPI *api = new tesseract::TessBaseAPI();
```

Comment: Locally your program may find DLL:s in many other places, not only in the release folder and if you've really linked statically with tesseract, I doubt that it will be the source of your problems. If you open the .exe from Visual Studio you should be able to see the DLL:s it's loading. Do the same on the target machine and see if it fails loading anything.

Comment: Don't forget about tessdata files which are used by tesseract. They were probably installed on your local machine with tesseract installation.

Comment: @TedLyngmo i tried to open the exe in vs and only see xml data which contains some assembly info also verified output window while building no info shown about tesseract dll.

Comment: @DmitriiZ. i already have placed tessdata files in server.

Comment: Can you run your code in debug mode from within the IDE on the target machine?

Comment: @TedLyngmo unfortunately i can't install vs on target machine

Comment: I'm not sure but doesn't VS support remote debugging of some sort?

Comment: @TedLyngmo yes VS has remote debugging for c++. thanks for the suggestion. it needs some ports enabled will do and update once i got port opened

Comment: Sounds promising!